# Fetch data from external API and populate database every minutes

Tags: node.js, linux, cron

I would like to fetch data from external API with limited request and populate my database. My concern is more about the architecture, language and tools to use. I would like to have a big picture in term of performance and good practise.

I did make an cron with nodejs and express running every minutes and populate my database and it works. On the same server i did created some routes to be called for client.

What should be better to do rather than using cron on nodejs ? I know that i can also make cron  under linux calling a script whatever it's python or nodejs. But what would be the good practise ? Specially if i want more cron instead of a single one ?

Should i separate my cron into another instance to not block any request from client ? If my server is already busy retrieving data from external API while someone is calling a route in the same server does it will increase the latency ?

There is some tools to monitor my tasks instead of using logs ?

Answer (score 1):

As i know node js is better to handle big amount of requests than a few other servers but if you are able to change the framework then you can give chance to https://bun.sh/.

also, you can try multithreading in node.js it can be more affordable and easy.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-multithreading-in-node-js